# Resize Terminal Console App with C# in Visual Studio (MacOSX)

Tags: c#, macos

I am trying to fullscreen my C# Visual studio console app, but to no success.

I tried a couple of methods but I am still new to creating console applications in Visual Studio, and nothing really worked. All I need is some C# code to get my terminal app into fullscreen on startup. I am on MacOSX, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @mathis1337 that is only for the Windows OS, I am on Mac, so this does not work for me.

Comment: Try using ANSI Terminal Commands - you may need to use `terminfo` and/or `tput` to verify the capabilities of your terminal window on macOS.

Comment: @Dai I'm not very experienced with this, but the only thing i got working was      
  "tput -V" and that just displayed "ncurses 5.7.20081102", also as I said I'm new to Visual Studio and C#, I have no idea how to use ANSI Terminal Commands. Any suggestions / examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use old fashioned escape commands I suppose. Here is a basic example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

[DllImport("libc")]
static extern int system(string exec);


system(@"printf '\e[8;50;100t'"); //adjust the 50 and 100t for whatever size you are wanting.
system(@"printf '\e[3;0;0t'"); // moves terminal to top left

while (true)
{
    var someText = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(someText);
}
```

Here is a video showing the size movements

[image]

Comment: Totally forgot about these escape commands.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago, I solved it using the "System.Runtime.InteropServices" APIs, do something like:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
     [DllImport("libc.dylib", EntryPoint = "system")]
     private static extern int System(string exec);

     static void Main()
     {
         const string command = "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to set bounds of front window to {0, 0, 1920, 1080}'";
         System(string.Format(command, Console.WindowWidth, Console.WindowHeight));

         Console.WriteLine("Full screen console application!");
         Console.ReadLine();
     }
}
```

Following something along those lines should solve your problem.

Comment: The code gives the error: "Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Text.ValueStringBuilder.ThrowFormatInvalidString()
   at System.Text.ValueStringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ReadOnlySpan`1 args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ReadOnlySpan1 args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0, Object arg1)", at this line: "System(string.Format(command, Console.WindowWidth, Console.WindowHeight));" It complains about something in the formatting?

Comment: @Jim Change `{0, 0, 1920, 1080}` to `{{0, 0, {0}, {1}}}`

Comment: It does change the terminal size, though I could only get the terminal to be smaller than usual. Changing any values except the first 2 to be higher than 1 does not work.